# Entity Framework Migrations to remote machine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF on a site at the moment, and using migrations when my model changes on my local machine which is updating a local SQL express database, a networked SQL database also works fine, which I've done on another project.

However now I've moved the solution to our development server and working on the solution files via our server, which is all working fine. But now for some reason I can't use migrations.. I've checked paths, and can't seem to find any errornous paths. I always get the error:

```
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///X:\path\to\site\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.
```

Is there some sort of configuration I need to set up to allow migrations to work from my local VS Pro (2010) to the production server (which is on our network)?
I have tried changing the init strategy to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and created a migration type from `DbMigrationsConfiguration`, setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to true, but it doesn't seem to update the database :/

Like I said, I can do migrations on an SQL server database which is on the development server from a local solution, but not when the solution is on the development server.

Am I trying to do something that is not possible, or just doing it wrong? Was thinking it's maybe something like Entity Framework perhaps not being installed on the server, but not too sure on that or how to really check.

Any ideas?

Thanks. Dan

Comment: I've actually worked out why the `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` wasn't working. I think it was due to there being data in the database and so it was throwing an internal error. I've discovered and set the aptly named `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` to true, and the auto migrations occur now. However I still would like to be able to add migrations manually.

Comment: I get this error when using Add-migration

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by, "you have moved the solution to the development server"?  Generally, you compile the code and release the compiled assemblies and content to the development server, and that code runs under IIS.  If you also have a development database on a development SQL Server that needs updated, you will need to run the update-database command from your development workstation and point your solution to the developement SQL Server.

You can point your solution to the development server by editing the config file for the startup project and setting either the connection string, or the default connection factory settings to point to your development SQL Server.

Comment: What I mean is, all the files I am working on in on another machine - the development server, and I am opening the solution from the development server. So no files are on my local machine. As mentioned, I can update the development server database when the solution was originally on my machine, but not now that the solution is elsewhere. I know the practice of working like this isn't ideal, but working via TFS or an SVN is impractical currently.